# I'm using my Own phone to run project in android. Can it damage my Phone easily?

Tags: android

In my company, they did not provide a phone for deployment or running the android project, so I'm forced to used my SAMSUNG GALAXY S 4.  What are your suggestions?  Should i buy a cheap phone only for debugging/running android apps or is it good to use my own phone? I'm just worried that my phone will be damaged for continued spamming uses of it.

What should I do?

Comment: There is no problem in use your own phone for that, only if your app need root permision to do something in your SO, if you are afraid of something you can always debug and test your app using an emulator...

Comment: I find the USB connection on the phone wears out because of the extra insertions.

Comment: This is not a programming related question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about using your own S4 for company purpose unless until you need to root your phone. Really Rooting is not a bad thing to worry about it. If you've a android project that needs to check Camera and Sensors then you should use a real device, But still there is an alternative to avoid using your own S4.

There is an emulator called [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), Even if you want to check camera or any other kind of sensors you can use that emulator to all the stuff. If you've found your emulator to be damn slow, I suggest you to use the GenyMotion, which is 10 times fast than the ADT emulator or else there is one more alternative to use a faster emulator with [INTEL HAXM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) which is same as like GenyMotion for faster emulator.

Chill :) Happy Coding

Comment: I read the genymotion it applies only to Android 2.3, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 but im using API Lv8 2.2 can i use it using 2.2?

Comment: you can run any app which meets the minimum requirment to the emulator android version. no prob..

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to actually mess up your phone with an app due to how apps are sandboxed.  This is especially true if your app remains at the SDK abstraction level, and doesn't mess around at the OS level.

Comment: What do you suggest, should i buy a cheap phone for programming purposes?

Comment: Not unless you are doing something that you have reason to believe will damage your phone.  I have been testing on my own devices for 4 years without breaking any of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're afraid that will damage your USB connector, you can use Wifi ADB to connect ADB via wifi, but you must have your phone rooted first.

Comment: What do you mean your phone should be rooted first?

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know you must rooted your phone to enable ADB debugging via wifi